# Starship symbols in Powershell

Tags: powershell, unicode

Is it at all possible to get a nice look, with symbols, with starship in PowerShell?
I've tried everything imaginable to get Fira Code font to show symbols in the console but always end up with ?? instead.

I know that the font is installed properly, because i can use Fira Code in notepad and other apps. But even when i select the correct font for PowerShell, it won't show any symbols. I've enabled the "Use unicode for world-wide language support" in Windows 10, and running chcp in Powershell returns Active code page: 65001.

Has anyone actually succeeded with this? Works great in Macos and Ubuntu, but i cannot get it right in Powershell. And by the way, i've tried both Powershell and Powershell Core.

Answer (score 1):

Fira Code seems to work fine in [Windows Terminal](https://aka.ms/terminal), you just need to update the profile settings for your PowerShell(s):

```
"profiles":
[
    {
        "guid": "{574e775e-4f2a-5b96-ac1e-a2962a402336}",
        "hidden": false,
        "name": "PowerShell",
        "source": "Windows.Terminal.PowershellCore",
        "fontFace": "Fira Code",
        "fontSize": 16
    }

]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, Windows Terminal seems to be the only solution. To bad it doesn't work directly in Powershell or WSL for that matter, nbut i can live with Windows Terminal as well.

Comment: Where is this file located?!

Comment: @PrimeByDesign `$installDir\LocalState\settings.json`, you can open it by clicking the down-arrow on the top bar and selecting `Settings` (or by pressing `[Ctrl+,]`)

Comment: Oh yeah I found it... Thank you. I realised I actually needed the settings.json for vscode

Answer (score 0):

Try the ISE, Vscode, or Windows Terminal.  Powershell 7 vs Powershell 5.